# How to get Telegram channel username from channel id without TG API?

Tags: telegram

I have list of telegram channels' id, but channel can change username. Is there any abilities to get username from id without using Tg API and Telethon, because it has many obstacles and query limits.

*Example*

> First period: channel's id: -1123123; username: test_channel
>
> Second period: channel's id: -1123123; (new) username: ?

**Is there function(id) -> channel's username?**

I tried go to telegram website via link [https://t.me/{group_id}](https://t.me/%7Bgroup_id%7D), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The telegram doesn't provide such APIs.
If you need to find a channel you only can use [TdApi.SearchPublicChat](https://tdlibx.github.io/td/docs/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi.SearchPublicChat.html) or [TdApi.SearchPublicChats](https://tdlibx.github.io/td/docs/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi.SearchPublicChats.html)